# How to build stock portfolio using deep reinforcement learning in Python by taking care of indicators for each given stock?

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, python-3.x, openai-gym

I have this Python code from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-Uw9gC3D4o) which is trading a stock (e.g. GME but it can be any) by taking care of its indicators ('SMA', 'RSI', 'OBV').

```
# Gym stuff
import gym
import gym_anytrading

# Stable baselines - rl stuff
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines import A2C

# Processing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Custom indicators libraries:
from gym_anytrading.envs import StocksEnv
from finta import TA

df = pd.read_csv('data/gmedata.csv')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.sort_values('Date', ascending=True, inplace=True)

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(5,250), window_size=5)

# Build Environment:
state = env.reset()
while True: 
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done: 
        print("info", info)
        break
        
#plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
#plt.cla()
#env.render_all()
#plt.show()

# Fix Volume Column:
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")))

# Calculate SMA, RSI and OBV:
df['SMA'] = TA.SMA(df, 12)
df['RSI'] = TA.RSI(df)
df['OBV'] = TA.OBV(df)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Create New Environments:
def add_signals(env):
    start = env.frame_bound[0] - env.window_size
    end = env.frame_bound[1]
    prices = env.df.loc[:, 'Low'].to_numpy()[start:end]
    signal_features = env.df.loc[:, ['Low', 'Volume','SMA', 'RSI', 'OBV']].to_numpy()[start:end]
    return prices, signal_features

class MyCustomEnv(StocksEnv):
    _process_data = add_signals
    
env2 = MyCustomEnv(df=df, window_size=12, frame_bound=(12,50))

# Build Environment and Train:
env_maker = lambda: env2
env = DummyVecEnv([env_maker])

model = A2C('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1) 
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000000)

# Evaluation:
env = MyCustomEnv(df=df, window_size=12, frame_bound=(80,250))
obs = env.reset()
while True: 
    obs = obs[np.newaxis, ...]
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        print("info", info)
        break

plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.cla()
env.render_all()
plt.show()
```

Here is the github repo for this code where you can find also the GME stock dataset too: https://github.com/nicknochnack/Reinforcement-Learning-for-Trading-Custom-Signals/blob/main/Custom%20Signals.ipynb

Now, let's say instead of feeding this deep RL code with just one stock ticker (GME) with its indicators values ('SMA', 'RSI', 'OBV') you feed it with a bunch of tickers (e.g. 100 or 1000 or so) and each of them to have their own indicators values.

How such a dataset should look like and how this code should be in order to accomplish such a thing because currently it is working for just one single ticker?

Comment: I don't have much experience with reinforcement learning, but if I'm not mistaken it would work exactly the same way (i.e. you use the same methodology to calculate the SAM, RSI, and OBV) except you just supply more columns to the environment.

Comment: @Oxbowerce There are a few problems with this approach: 1) it must choose more tickets according to their indicators not just a single one, so how to set up this? 2) how would it know which are tickets and which are their indicators in order to choose only the indicators to trade and not the indicators too? 3) how it would know which indicators are for which tickers?

Comment: If I understand you correctly the concern you have is that the column names will be the same for different tickers and you can't distinguish between the tickers. This can be solved by get the data for all the tickers and making sure that the column names are descriptive, e.g. `GME_Volume` for the volume of the GME ticker and `GME_SMA` for the simple moving average values of the GME ticker.

Comment: @Oxbowerce So, doing this way, how the algorithm itself could know to trade and build a portfolio consisting of tickers (stocks) and not tickers (stocks) and their indicators too? e.g. PORTFOLIO: 7 shares of TSLA, 12 shares of MSFT and 23 shares of GME_SMA ---> which is wrong as GME_SMA is not something to buy, it is just an indicator that it should take care when buying or selling stocks.